# How to check data update using selenium webdriver?

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having job portal for testing. I am testing that once job seeker update his/her resume then actually all field data is updating or not?

I have automated above for easy and fast regression testing. At this time I am doing like :

1 - Store resume data in to excel - **Before Update**

2 - Update Resume data

3 - Store resume data again into same excel - **After Update**

4 - Now I am comparing cell data of  **Before Update** & **After Update** one by one and checking that if data matches or mismatches. If data mismatch then it means data updated.

So Am I doing it in right way? Is there any other easy way in selenium webdriver to check above things , I mean to check whether data is updated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you 2 approaches:-

1) Without using excel sheet:-(Recommended)
- you can use hash map(key-value) to store data before updating resume.
- Then After updating resume, you can store updated values in another map.
- Now, you can compare both map data.

2) Using excel sheet:(Only if you need to data for future reference)
- Yes, in this case, as you did, save data in 2 different sheets of same worksheet of an excel file.
- Use poi jar, to retrieve and write data in these excel sheets.
- Compare data for verification. But using excel should be avoided if not required to store data for future reference. Excel have chances to get corrupt and also excel connection is little bit time consuming as compared to 1st approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now I am using your 2nd approach. Can you pleas share link where it has example like how to work with Hash map?

Comment: //import:-
import java.util.HashMap;

//Hashmap declaration:-
HashMap<String, String> myMap= new HashMap<String, String>();

//Insert data in map (key,value):-

myMap.put("Name", "Helping Hand");//here Name is key and Helping Hand is value
myMap.put("Company", "XYZ technologies");

//Retrieving data from map:-

String name = myMap.get("Name"); //this will return "Helping Hand"
String company = myMap.get("Company"); //this will return "XYZ technologies"

Refer link - http://www.javatpoint.com/HashMap-class-in-collection-framework

Google for more info on hash maps.